# Can the affixes on an item tell me if it's desirable?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are affixes in a specific item type rare enough to make an item highly desirable?

For example, and I'm making this up, is +INT on pants rarer than +INT on 1-Hand weapons?

Are some affixes so much rarer than others that just by seeing them I should know it would sell for high amounts of gold in the AH?

I'm actually looking for ways to quickly and at a glance know if I can sell an item easily for millions of gold, instead of having to manually search for similar items and see for how much they sell.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/77706/how-can-i-determine-what-the-current-market-value-of-my-items-are

Comment: Currently, it seems items require a "trifecta" of attack speed, crit chance, and crit damage in order to be worth much of anything.  Primary stat and vit on top of that is pure gravy.

Comment: @fbueckert no, not really.  Trifecta makes it highly desirable, but for gloves just having 2 out of the three with dual stat or single stat + res already makes it super expensive.

Comment: most of what I said [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/71617/3917) still applies

Comment: and afaik there's no such thing as 'rarity' of affixes.  They all appear equally likely, but some affixes are more desirable than others.

Answer (score 3):

With the way the AH has been flooded with items, there's no clear way of knowing whether an item will sell for a lot or a little outside of looking at the actual numbers.

http://www.d3rmt.com/guides/diablo-3-item-stat-maximum-values/ This website has the maximum value for every stat in every slot possible, so you can use that as a guideline for whether you think your item will sell for a lot.  Obviously, stat combinations are going to play a huge role too, so rolling 300 int on a helm with nothing else is going to be worth less than say...200 int with 4% crit and an open socket.